# AVISaveOptions without AVIStream

Tags: winapi, video, avi, vfw

I am coding a program which exports AVI files into directories, is it possible to get an AVISaveOptions dialog without having access to an avistream? The AVICOMPRESSOPTIONS already has all the data, doesn't it? I am not able to create a stream using AVICreateStream because I do not know its parameter and the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756821(v=vs.85).aspx) does not explain them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AVISaveOptions` API passes call to [`ICCompressorChoose`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd742967) and the API looks up ICM codec from the stream you provide as an argument. This is why streams are required input. You need `ICCompressorChoose` instead if you don't have [yet] a stream.